# Ternary Operator within an Each statement not working in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

I was wondering if this is a syntax issue or ternary operators don't work within an each statement?

Below is the code (code is on the 2nd line

```
def no_repeats(year_start, year_end)
    (year_start..year_end).each {|x| no_repeats?(x) ? puts x: puts "nil"}
end




def no_repeats?(year)
    splitted_year = year.to_s.split("")
    counter=[]
    splitted_year.each {|x| counter << x unless counter.include?(x)}
    if counter.count == 4
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
end


no_repeats(1980,1985)
```

The following code solves this

```
(year_start..year_end).each {|x| no_repeats?(x) ? puts(x) : puts("nil") }
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: It seems that we have to put "()" around the arguments for puts in the ternary operator to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's syntax issue. Put space before the colon and surround arguments to `puts` with parentheses (to remove ambiguities).

```
(year_start..year_end).each {|x| no_repeats?(x) ? puts(x) : puts("nil") }
```

Comment: Or just use `if` like everybody else.